# Add a single quote to a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, postgresql, casting, parameter-passing, psycopg2

I want to use an SQL output string to query some data in PostgreSQL using Python. I'm using Python 2.7.

For example:

> The output string is `mike`
>   I want to have `mike` as `'mike'` to be valid as an input.

This is my code:

```
formated_fix_names = ''.join(author_name_fix_list)).replace(' ', '\'')
```

The problem is I need to pass this string to an SQL code as `name = 'mike'`:

```
cursor.execute("select author_name from commits where commit_hash in ("+formated_fix_names+")")
```

The problem must be at this part I think `.replace(' ', '\'')`.

Comment: no, this syntax `formated_fix_hashes = ''.join(fix_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\"', '\'')` worked to convert ["80f3bcb58f836cfe"] into '80f3bcb58f836cfe'

Comment: The problem is `''.join(author_name_fix_list))`, try remove the last `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mess with string manipulation. [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) does the right thing by [adapting a Python `list` to a Postgresql `array`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types):

```
author_list = ['John','Mary']
query = """
    select author_name
    from commits
    where commit_hash = any (%s)
"""
print cursor.mogrify(query, (author_list,))
#cursor.execute(query, (author_list,))
```

Output:

```
select author_name
from commits
where commit_hash = any (ARRAY['John', 'Mary'])
```

Notice that the `list` must be passed to the [`cursor.execute`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method wrapped in an iterable.

The `in` syntax can be used if the `list` is cast to a `tuple`:

```
author_list = ['John','Mary']
query = """
    select author_name
    from commits
    where commit_hash in %s
"""
print cursor.mogrify(query, (tuple(author_list),))
#cursor.execute(query, (tuple(author_list),))
```

Output:

```
select author_name
from commits
where commit_hash in ('John', 'Mary')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes(`""`), for example:

```
name = "mike"
result = "'" + name + "'"
```

Comment: I think something should be done in this part  .replace(' ', '\'')

Comment: Please use 4 space before code to format code in readable format, check the [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn the string mike into the string 'mike' you can use this expression:

```
name = "mike"
newName = "'%s'" % name
```

This turns name, which contains the string mike, into newName, which contains the string mike with single quotes around it, which you should now be able to use. I hope this helps!